# Is there a way to change android sqlite data?

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I want to swap sqlite data
now, I am changing data after saving it in a variable
Is there a better way? Thank you

```
updateDbDate(fromItem.getTitle(),fromItem.getCable(),fromItem.getImg(),toItem.getId());
updateDbDate(toItem.getTitle(),toItem.getCable(), toItem.getImg(),fromItem.getId());

public void updateDbDate(String mTitle, String mCable, String mImg, int id)
{
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

    values.put("title", mTitle);
    values.put("cable", mCable);
    values.put("bimg", mImg);

    db.update(Define.DB, values,"_id = " + "'" + id + "'",null);
}
```

Comment: Are there only these 4 columns in the table?

Comment: yes, There are only four columns

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I understand is that you want to swap the values of 3 columns between 2 rows for which you know the ids.
If you also know the values of the other 3 columns then your method is correct.
If you don't know them and you have to read them from the table then I think it would be better to just swap the ids:

```
public void swapIds(int id1, int id2) {
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put("_id", -1);
    db.update(Define.DB, values, "_id = ?", new String[] {String.valueOf(id1)});
    values.put("_id", id1);
    db.update(Define.DB, values, "_id = ?", new String[] {String.valueOf(id2)});
    values.put("_id", id2);
    db.update(Define.DB, values, "_id = ?", new String[] {"-1"});
    db.close();
}
```

The 1st update sets temporarily `-1` to the first `_id`, because I guess it is the `PRIMARY KEY` and it can't be set to `id2` because it already exists.
The 2nd update sets `id1` to the second `_id` (it can be done since `id1` does not exist in the table from the previous update).
And the 3d update sets `id2` to the first `_id`.
Now you can call the method:

```
swapIds(100, 200);
```

**Note**: this method is not recommended if there are references in other tables to the `_id` of this table.